# Gruntfile Aborting file

Tags: javascript, html, json, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I have downloaded foundation 5, but having issues adding plugins onto the default config. I understand the installation of the plugin from a console point of view. However I struggle after including & registering the task, to correctly code the Gruntfile.js

Gruntfile.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    watch: {
      options: {
          livereload: true
      },

      css: {
        files: {
            'css/app.css': 'scss/apps.css',
            'css/custom.css': 'scss/custom.scss'
        },
        tasks: ['sass', 'concat'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
      },

      scripts: {
        files: ['js/dev/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
      }
    },

    sass: {

      options: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
      },

      dist: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'nested'
        },

        expand: true,
        cwd: 'scss/',
        src: {
            'css/app.css': 'scss/apps.css',
            'css/custom.css': 'scss/custom.scss'
        },
        dest: 'css/',
        ext: '.css'    
      }
    },

    jshint: {
      src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'js/dev/script.js'],
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
      }
    },

    uglify: {
        build: {
            files: {
                'js/dev/plugins/*.js': ['js/dev/plugins.min.js'],
                'js/dev/script.min.js': ['js/dev/script.min.js']
            }
        }
    },

    concat : {
        bar: {
            'js/dev/script.min.js': ['js/build/script.min.js?<%= pkg.version %>']
        }
    },

    imagemin: {  
        static: {  
          options: {
            optimizationLevel: 3
          },
          files: {                         
            'lossy-images/*.png': 'images/*.png', 
            'lossy-images/*.jpg': 'images/*.jpg',
            'lossy-images/*.gif': 'images/*.gif'
          }
        },
        dynamic: {                         
          files: [{
            expand: true,                  
            cwd: 'images/',                   
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],   
            dest: 'lossy-images/'                  
          }]
        }
      }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build','watch', 'jshint', 'concat', 'uglify', 'imagemin']);
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "example-site",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.5.0"
  }
}
```

.jshitrc Contents

```
{
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "immed": true,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "sub": true,
  "undef": true,
  "boss": true,
  "eqnull": true,
  "node": true,
  "browser" : true,

    "globals": {
      "jQuery": true,
      "require" : true,
      "define" : true,
      "requirejs" : true,
      "describe" : true,
      "expect" : true,
      "it" : true,
      "module" : true,
    }
}
```

Livereload - html code

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Conclusion:

Live reload does not work (I have installed the chrome extension). I am getting the following errors:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I have yet to include compass / Autoprefixer for my mixin needs. If you took the time to scroll or read, thanks.

I welcome any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to change sass section as below:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'nested'
    },

    files: [         
      {src: 'css/app.css', dest: 'scss/apps.css'},
      {src: 'css/custom.css', dest: 'scss/custom.scss'}
    ]       
  }
}
```

More information about files object format options you can find here: 
 http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format

Comment: Thanks worked great so far, could you explain the difference between, dist / foo / bar. I now understand the syntax better but unsure of the child braces between calling the files and the sass main brace.

Comment: dist/foo/bar is only name of section, it may be ololol as well as tratata, it is only name, that you could use e.g. sass:ololo.

Comment: How could I go about running a a development version (nested css) and one which is production (minified)?